# How to open Vmware(centos) apache server from hostmachine(Windows) browser

Tags: linux, centos, vmware-workstation

I am trying to open Apache tomcat (installed on VMware Centos) from Windows browser.
ssh is working fine from windows to centos.
but when i typed http://192.168.67.131:8080 or https on windows browser, i am unable to open it from windows.

But from centos browser,i can see the apache console with same port and ip address.(http://192.168.67.131:8080)

These is my centos ipconfig,I tried using both Bridge,NAT,host-only these things doesn't worked.

1: lo:  mtu 65526 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN

```
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

2:
 eno16777736:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:32:ef:25:41 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.67.131/24 brd 192.168.67.255 scope global dynamic eno16777736
       valid_lft 1580sec preferred_lft 1580sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feef:6551/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Can some one help me to solve these issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what version of Centos are you using? Either check iptables or firewalld and open port 80 and/or 443

`cat /etc/redhat-release`

if on version before 7

`iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers`

if on version 7 or greater

`firewall-cmd --list-all`

if port is not listed in the print out, then enter either command for iptables or firewalld

`iptables -A INPUT -s YOUR_SUBNET -d 192.168.67.131 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port 8080/tcp && firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: glad to hear it, the firewall default rule set has caught me a few times